# Unable to fill values into text box using autoit script with firefox?

Tags: mozilla, autoit

i am unable to fill values into text box ?i have tried following code..``

```
$url = "file:///C:/Users/Desktop/HTML.html"
    $formID = ""
    $formUID = "username"
    $uName = "srv.iloadmin"
    $formPID = "password"
    $pwd = "SeR^ER@iL0"
    $formSubmit = "ID_LOGON" 
    Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & $url, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
    _FFSetValue($uName,$formUID,"id")
    _FFSetValue($pwd,$formPID,"id")
```

HTML script  username is:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="textfield" name="username" id="username" size="30" onkeypress="return checkEnter(event);" type="text">
```

Password:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="textfield" name="password" id="password" size="30" onkeypress="return checkEnter(event);" type="password">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a closer look at [Firefox UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/)

Here is a simple example:

```
#Include <FF.au3>

_FFConnect()
If _FFIsConnected() Then
_FFOpenUrl("http://www.example.com/news/811")
 _FFLoadWait()
_FFClick(".forms[2].elements[0]")
_FFLoadWait()
EndIf
```